# compare 3 lists and delete all matched elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hy,

I want to compare 3 lists and whenever a match occurs, the elements of the lists will deleted.

( --> every time gpos = G00 and xpos = 0 and ypos = 0 )

```
gpos = ['G01','G01','G00','G00','G00','G00','G00','G00','G00','G00']
xpos = ['249','248', '0' , '0' , '72', '0' , '66','67' ,'81' , '82']
ypos = ['18', '28' , '0' , '0' , '52', '0',  '53','55' ,'54' , '52']

---------------------
the output should be:
---------------------

gpos = ['G01','G01','G00',G00','G00','G00','G00']
xpos = ['249','248', '72','66','67' ,'81' , '82']
ypos = ['18', '28' , '52','53','55' ,'54' , '52']
```

I have no idea what to do O_o

Comment: What matches there? Do you basically want to remove duplicates? Or do you just want to remove it whenever you have a `G00`?

Comment: SO is about programming. What did you program so far? Show it to us!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is rather crude, but it would work.

```
for index,element in enumerate(xpos):
 if element == '0':
  if ypos[index] == '0':
   if gpos[index] == 'G00':
    del gpos[index]
    del xpos[index]
    del ypos[index]
```

Just to add to this, you should have atleast tried something and put it with the question. It doesn't matter how much wrong you are, but you should try your best to code on your own.

Comment: Deleting elements from a list while you are iterating on it will not work as you intend. You'll end up skipping some values, and you'll get the wrong results if two values that should be deleted are adjacent to each other (as they are in the example input).

Comment: You're welcome, if this answer is correct for you, should close the question; set this answer as your accepted answer @InvAdErZz

Comment: @Blckknght However, in the case that Invaderzz has asked, I don't think so that would happen. But in general, I completely agree what you're trying to say

Comment: I can't see how this code works for the questioner. If I run it with the example data provided, I do not get the desired output. The fourth item in each list do not get removed.

Comment: @sgp this answer is wrong, both in the general case, and in the case given by the questioner.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `izip` from `itertools`, and iterate on your 3 lists at the same time.

Then, when `xpos` and `ypos` are equal to `'0'`, drop the tuple.

```
new_gpos = list()
new_xpos = list()
new_ypos = list()

for (a,b,c) in itertools.izip(gpos, xpos, ypos):
    if not (b == c == '0'):
        print a, b, c
        new_gpos.append(a)
        new_xpos.append(b)
        new_ypos.append(c)
```

Comment: The question is tagged [python-3.x], so regular old `zip` will work like `itertools.izip` did in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

```python
# Input data
gpos = ['G01','G01','G00','G00','G00','G00','G00','G00','G00','G00']
xpos = ['249','248', '0' , '0' , '72', '0' , '66','67' ,'81' , '82']
ypos = ['18', '28' , '0' , '0' , '52', '0',  '53','55' ,'54' , '52']

# Input match (as a tuple)
match = ('G00', '0', '0')
```

You can transpose them back and forth (consider columns instead of rows) and filter.

```
# Flipper
transpose = lambda x: [list(col) for col in zip(*x)]

# Filter input
gpos, xpos, ypos = transpose([col for col in zip(gpos, xpos, ypos) if col != match])

print gpos # ['G01', 'G01', 'G00', 'G00', 'G00', 'G00', 'G00']
print xpos # ['249', '248', '72',  '66',  '67',  '81',  '82']
print ypos # ['18',  '28',  '52',  '53',  '55',  '54',  '52']
```

Alternative one-liner (as suggested by Blckknght):

```
gpos, xpos, ypos = map(list, zip(*[gxy for gxy in zip(gpos, xpos, ypos) if gxy != match]))
```

Comment: Rather than making a single `filtered` list and indexing it, you could do an assignment back to `gpos`, `xpos` and `ypos` with the results. This would let you use a generator like `map` rather than a list comprehension in `transpose` (though I'd just write the whole thing inline: `gpos, xpos, ypos = map(list, zip(*[gxy for gxy in zip(gpos, xpos, ypos) if gxy != match]))`).